# uid of parent page or pid of current page for Typoscript db queries

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want a list of uids of the current active parent of my menu. I got a solution, which gives me exactly that, however, my solution is really static, as it doesn't take the current active "parent" menu but a fixed value i typed in. Here is my code:

```
lib.dbValues = CONTENT
lib.dbValues {
table = pages
select {
   selectFields = uid
   pidInList = 74
}
renderObj = TEXT
renderObj {
    field = uid
    wrap = |,
   }
}
```

My question would be, can i get the Pid of the current page or the uid of the parent page dynamically? it really bothers me that i can get the current uid by typing "this" but nothing else.

Comment: I found a workaround and ran into the next problem. I wanted to add a "where" clause to the query and select the pid of the current page, so it would look like this: 
    where = pid in ( SELECT pid FROM pages WHERE uid = 78)
However, the "pidinlist" property breakes the query as it compares. "Where pid in ({uid of page}) AND pid in (74)". Is there a way to ignore the pidinlist property? I am trying to break it but without any success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround that i will use for now (untill i have a better grasp on how to typoscript). I just broke the query condition with a marker:

```
lib.dbValues = CONTENT
lib.dbValues {
table = pages
select {
   selectFields = uid
   #pidInList = pid
   where = pid NOT IN (0) OR pid IN (SELECT pid FROM pages WHERE uid = ###THIS_UID###)
   markers {
        THIS_UID.data = TSFE:id
    }
}
renderObj = TEXT
renderObj {
    field = uid
    wrap = |,
    }
}
```

With the Where clause i will get something like

```
... WHERE pid in (0) and pid NOT IN (0) OR ...
```

Everything in front of the or is insicnificant. It seemed like typo is trying very hard to not get the current page id comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
select.where = colPos = 4     
select.orderBy = sorting
select.andWhere.wrap = pid=|
select.andWhere.data = page:uid
```